# shadowRadius doesn't blur the shadow

Tags: ios, shadow, scenekit

I'm trying to set a blurry shadow on my box. This is what I got so far.[image]

The documentation on shadowRadius says.

> SceneKit produces soft-edged shadows by rendering the silhouettes of
>   geometry into a 2D shadow map and then using several weighted samples
>   from the shadow map to determine the strength of the shadow at each
>   pixel in the rendered scene. This property controls the radius of
>   shadow map sampling. Lower numbers result in shadows with sharply
>   defined, pixelated edges; higher numbers result in blurry shadows.

this is my shadow setup code

```
func setupShadow(){
        spotLight.castsShadow = true
        spotLight.shadowRadius = 30000
        spotLight.shadowBias = 1
        spotLight.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
```

As you can see, the shadow radius is set to a huge number but the shadow remains edgy. In fact, blurriness does not even change if shadowRadius changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want a smaller radius (like [1; 3]).

Then on iOS you also need to specify the number of sample using **shadowSampleCount** (because the default is only 1 sample on iOS which implies no blur).
Beware that increasing the number of samples will improve the quality but it has a significant impact on performance.

Comment: Great! For future readers: once shadowSampleCount was set I also needed to set the zNear of the light in order to make shadow visible. Before setting shadowSampleCount that was not needed.